# Why is receiving from a channel ordered in Golang?

Tags: go, goroutine

Here is an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
        go func(i int) {
            for {
                n := <-ch
                fmt.Printf("Goroutine %d got %d\n", i, n)
            }
        }(i)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
        ch <- i
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
}
```

After the first loop, we have 5 goroutines that are waiting for messages from the channel.
Then, we have the second loop. My expectations were that messages would be delivered to the random goroutines. Unfortunately, the output is always the same:

```
Goroutine 0 got 0
Goroutine 1 got 1
Goroutine 2 got 2
Goroutine 3 got 3
Goroutine 4 got 4
Goroutine 0 got 5
Goroutine 1 got 6
Goroutine 2 got 7
Goroutine 3 got 8
Goroutine 4 got 9
Goroutine 0 got 10
Goroutine 1 got 11
Goroutine 2 got 12
Goroutine 3 got 13
Goroutine 4 got 14
Goroutine 0 got 15
Goroutine 1 got 16
Goroutine 2 got 17
Goroutine 3 got 18
Goroutine 4 got 19
```

The delivery order, in this case, is first-come-first-got. Is it documented?

How can I change the behavior and deliver each message to a random goroutine?

Comment: A chan is a queue but if multiple goroutines are reading from the same chan *at the same time* then which succeeds (gets the next value from the chan) is indeterminate.  The trouble is your sleeps and printfs collude so that only one goroutine is trying to read the chan at a time.  Try removing your sleeps.

Comment: There is no sleep in goroutine loop:

```
for {
  n := <-ch
  fmt.Printf("Goroutine %d got %d\n", i, n)
}
```

Comment: Go already functions the way you wish it would. Your code is specifically set up to provoke the behaviour you're complaining about. Remove the `time.Sleep` and run it on realistic workloads.

Comment: Why do you think the problem in my example is the sleep? There is no sleep inside goroutines. The first sleep is used to get a deterministic order of how the goroutines start waiting for messages. And they all are waiting at the same time. The second sleep in the sending part is used to give time to point a message and be sure that all goroutines are ready again.

Answer (score 1):

> *The delivery order, in this case, is first-come-first-got. Is it documented?*

Yes, in [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Channel_types).

> Channels act as first-in-first-out queues. For example, if one goroutine sends values on a channel and a second goroutine receives them, the values are received in the order sent.

> *How can I change the behavior and deliver each message to a random goroutine?*

AFAIK there is no way to alter the channel implementation. Simplest option would be to randomize your channel input.

***However***, the apparent neat order is only there because you're sleeping. Sleep in concurrent code is generally a bad sign. There's no way to predict how long each operation will take, so you wind up with either conservatively long sleeps leading to inefficient code, or sleeps that are sometimes too short leading to hard to debug errors.

There's no need to sleep when working with channels. If you try to send to a channel which has no room, the send will block. If you try to receive from a channel with nothing in it, the receive will block.

If you remove the sleeps and let Go operate concurrently, the nice neat order will go away. Instead, use channel buffering and [sync.WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) to coordinate.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Note that production code would add a buffer here.
    // Without a buffer, workers will wait for input.
    // A buffer at least equal to the number of workers will run
    // more efficiently.
    ch := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        // Add the new worker to the wait group. Basically just increments a counter.
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(i int) {
            // Tell the wait group this worker is done. Basically decrements a counter.
            // defer ensures this will happen no matter how the function exits, even if it errors.
            defer wg.Done()

            // Using range(ch) lets the loop exit once the channel is closed
            for n := range(ch) {
                fmt.Printf("Goroutine %d got %d\n", i, n)
            }
        }(i)
    }
    
    // Because ch has no buffer, this will wait until a worker reads from
    // the channel before adding another value.
    // This is causing a bottleneck as workers wait for input.
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }

    // Close the channel so workers know there is no more input coming.
    close(ch)
    
    // main() will not wait for goroutines to finish.
    // This will wait until all workers call wg.Done().
    wg.Wait()
}
```

[Demonstration](https://play.golang.com/p/Ka-oq6TY7ZA).

Now that we're allowing everything to operate concurrently, the order of processing will not exactly be random, but also won't be quite so ordered as each goroutine reads from the channel as fast as they can. Here is one possible output, it will vary from run to run.

```
Goroutine 4 got 0
Goroutine 4 got 5
Goroutine 3 got 2
Goroutine 3 got 7
Goroutine 3 got 8
Goroutine 3 got 9
Goroutine 0 got 1
Goroutine 0 got 11
Goroutine 2 got 4
Goroutine 2 got 13
Goroutine 2 got 14
Goroutine 2 got 15
Goroutine 2 got 16
Goroutine 1 got 3
Goroutine 1 got 18
Goroutine 4 got 6
Goroutine 2 got 17
Goroutine 0 got 12
Goroutine 3 got 10
Goroutine 1 got 19
```

In this case the first 5 reads from the channel were...

0. Goroutine 4
1. Goroutine 0
2. Goroutine 3
3. Goroutine 1
4. Goroutine 2

Then 4 finished its loop first and read 5 from the channel. And so on.

---

To better understand the code above, I recommend reading [Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/) starting at [Goroutines](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines) and continuing on until [WaitGroups](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups).

Comment: Why do you think the problem in my example is the sleep? The is not sleep inside goroutines. The first sleep is used to get deterministic order how the goroutines starts waiting messages. And they all are waiting at the same time. The second sleep in the sending part is used to give time to proint message and be sure, that all goroutines are ready again.

Comment: @dhythhsba And that's why you're getting neatly ordered deterministic output (somewhat deterministic, because you can't know how long to sleep before all goroutines are ready, you'd still use things like channels and WaitGroups), ***because you specifically coded for it***. If you don't code for it, processing happens whenever channels and goroutines are ready and processing will happen out of order; this is the intended way to do concurrency in Go. If you want true randomness, you'd code it like I have (again, sleep in concurrent code doesn't really work) and randomize your channel inputs.

Comment: @dhythhsba Put another way, the sort of lock-step coding you're doing defeats the point of having channels. You could simply have a loop that calls 5 goroutines passing in 5 inputs.

Comment: I have changed a bit the code above: https://go.dev/play/p/bt9b_0jB4qq?v=gotip Let's treat the sleeps and we do something useful. Let's think that the processing time on the receiver side is always smaller than waiting for the next task. Do you see the pattern again?

Comment: @dhythhsba It's the sleep inside the input loop. The sleep and lack of a channel buffer effectively allows only one goroutine to run at a time **defeating the point of concurrency**. If you only want one goroutine to run at a time, you might as well just loop and print, its simpler and faster. [Remove the sleep and it's back to being concurrent](https://go.dev/play/p/AntBnllkF5i?v=gotip). Why do you want to sleep? [What are you trying to accomplish?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @dhythhsba "*Let's think that the processing time on the receiver side is always smaller than waiting for the next task.*" If it takes longer to add input than to process it, why do you need more than one worker?

Comment: "If it takes longer to add input than to process it, why do you need more than one worker?" That is a very good question.  My example in the initial post is the simplified version of real code. The goal of real code is to pick a random worker.  In other words, it is sampling. And I expected that when multiple goroutines are waiting for the next message from an unbuffered channel,  then the random goroutine will get the next message. But the message is always delivered to the goroutine which started to wait first. It is a surprise to me. I want to find where it is documented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256827/discussion-between-schwern-and-dhythhsba).